# Solved: Able to read nodejs source code by directly accessing website.com/index.js

Tags: node.js

Unless after every git push I chmod the index.js file to 771, the source code, index.js, is provided to the browser as plaintext when accessed through url.  The public folder set to static works, but this file and other folders in the directory, such as sessions, are still accessible.  I have tried .htaccess because I am using shared hosting with apache.  I feel like it is missing something simple.

And Nelles was correct, I was serving directly from the server folder, and had the .htaccess in the wrong place.

Directory:

```
app
--node_modules
--public
--sessions
--views
index.js
package.json
.htaccess
```

Comment: NodeJS has to run as a server ideally through a port number which you delegate.  You may be making the mistake of trying to serve the files up with a direct path to a public folder.

Comment: I'm connecting through a port, and everything has been working as it should, I was just curious what would happen, and sure enough, sessions provides a directory, and the index.js just prints it out in plain text.  I'm just not sure what I would need to change with node.

Comment: Can't mark yours as the answer, @Nelles but moving the app folder away from public_html and putting the correct .htaccess in public_html did the trick!

Comment: I will post it as a formal solution so you can mark it for others who may encounter the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

NodeJS has to run as a server ideally through a port number which you delegate. You may be making the mistake of trying to serve the files up with a direct path to a public folder.

You can put this in your .htaccess or apache conf file.  The following is if you want to have NodeJS listen on port 5000 but serve on /server

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyRequests Off

ProxyPass /server http://localhost:5000
ProxyPassReverse /server http://localhost:5000
```